# Access the web through SOCKS, SSH and then HTTP Proxy

Tags: ssh, proxy, putty, tunnel, socks-proxy

WGH

The web is full of guides like [this](http://www.sotechdesign.com.au/browsing-the-web-through-a-ssh-tunnel-with-firefox-and-putty-windows/), explaining how to make firefox using SOCKS connection to an SSH tunnel.

It Almost fits my needed. I have followed the instructions and it works fine, but there is a problem. The SSH tunnel is configured in the server to work only on a local group of servers, unless another specific proxy is configured.

I mean that when opening a terminal and trying to browse the web, say with w3m, access is only to *.institue.com. If you want for example to browse superuser.com, you have to set HTTP_PROXY variable to somepredifinedproxy.com:port.

I have tried using Proxy Cap and define this seuqence, when i checked the connection in that tool' GUI it worked just fine, but i couldn't make it work on firefox for some reason.

[image: that's how it look]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made it after a while.
I had to define two more things:

On putty:

[image: putty]

On firefox:

[image]